# Age as a time scale in survival analysis

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

In survival analysis, you measure the time from some startpoint and right censor your data. The code thus usually looks like this:

```
fit <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ outcome + x1 + x2, data=db)
```

However, in epidemiological analysis, the startpoint is not informative (i.e. it just indicates one completed a form, not that one is exposed to something), so the data is said to be left truncated and the measured time has to be adjusted.

I've been told to overcome this limit by using age as the time-scale, which makes perfectly sense as my outcome can be related to age.

This seems easily doable [with SAS](https://www.lexjansen.com/wuss/2003/DataAnalysis/i-cox_time_scales.pdf) (end of page 5). How can I achieve this with R ?

Comment: Assuming that you have a variable `age` that indicates the subject age at the start of follow-up (in the same units as `time`), use `Surv(age, age + time, status)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but `Surv` help says "time2 : ending time of the interval for interval censored or counting process data only", how this relates ? As I understand it, your code means "status event occured somewhere between `age` and `age+time`", which is not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hmmm, but the `heart` example is not consistent with what I just said. It seems I have misunderstood something. Could you explain a little more your suggestion ? (as an answer maybe ?)

Comment: @MikkoMarttila when I do what you wrote, I get very strange KM curves, where subjects at risk are not decreasing over time, and I'm not sure what time axis really stands for.

Comment: The arguments to `Surv` follow rather complex rules for interpretation, but three unnamed arguments with a logical 3rd argument are used to specify a "counting process" data structure that allows left-truncated and right-censored data. You may find e.g. the start of [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) helpful with that.

Comment: With regards to the KM curves, the time axis stands for age. As study entry times are scattered across the age scale for subjects, it follows that the size of the risk set does not (necessarily) decrease monotonically across the axis.

Comment: You vignette link is gold, thanks ! About the KM curves, it seems that an event occuring in a rare time period get a abnormal importance. For instance, if I have only 2 20yo people and most of my dataset is composed of 50+yo people, if one of my 20yo people have an event, my curve will litterally start from 50% survival. Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes that's exactly right. Of course your measures for uncertainty in the curve will also be massive, since the start is based on so little information. That can definitely be problematic when you have sparse data spread across a wide range of ages.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila Hi, I'm doing a bit of cleaning, if you mind to write your comment as an answer, I'd gladly accept it